# mysql order by multiple columns with if

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT s.name, s.mark, g.grade FROM students s, grades g
where g.grade = ( Select grade from grades where s.mark >= min_mark and s.mark <= max_mark)
order by IF(g.grade='F' or g.grade='E' or g.grade='D', (g.grade, s.mark), g.grade)
```

This is the mysql syntax that I am trying but not getting it to work.

The select works as intended, but I want to order the grades from A to F and on same grades I want to order the marks desc for A-C and asc for D-F

Hope it's clear what I want:

```
name            grade     mark
Ewan Black         A      100
Ryan Richards      B      90
Drake Porter       C      78
Jamie Miller       C      76
NULL               D      67
NULL               F      43
NULL               F      54
```

Comment: Not sure if i got the idea but `ORDER BY g.grade ASC, IF(g.grade > 'C',-s.mark,s.mark) DESC` might do the trick

Comment: yeah it did :P thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Vatev noted, you can use a conditional statement to change the 2nd value being sorted. I would recommend using a `CASE` statement, as it's more compliant with SQL standards. Also, I would recommend you use the standard `JOIN` syntax, rather than the old-style (20-year-plus) joins. Also, you don't need a sub-query. So something like this:

```
select
    students.name
    ,grades.grade
    ,students.mark
from students
    inner join grades on
        students.mark between grades.min_mark and grades.max_mark
order by
    grades.grade
    ,case
        when grades.grade in ('D', 'E', 'F')
            then students.mark
        else
            100 - students.mark
    end
```